# How to programmatically invoke the native datepicker on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I want to programmatically kick off the native datepicker on my web page (that is run on iOS and Android).  I know that I can use `<input type="date"` but that would require user input.

How do I kick it off programmatically?

Comment: Maybe try triggering a focus event on the input?

Comment: @BrianGlaz No it won't populate calendar.

Comment: @RahilWazir Yep, that was the first thing I tried.  I also tried to trigger a click event programmatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The web platform now ships with the HTMLInputElement `showPicker()` method, a canonical way to show a browser picker not only for dates, but also time, color, and files. At the time of writing, `showPicker()` is available in Chrome 99 or later.

Calling showPicker() on an  element shows a browser picker to the user. It must be called in response to a user gesture such as a touch gesture or mouse click; otherwise it will fail with a NotAllowedError exception. For security reasons, it will throw a SecurityError exception when it's called in a cross-origin iframe.

A browser picker is shown when the  element is one of these types: "date", "month", "week", "time", "datetime-local", "color", or "file".

The example below shows you how to open a browser date picker.

```html
<input type="date">
<button>Show the date picker</button>

<script>
  const button = document.querySelector("button");
  const dateInput = document.querySelector("input");

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    try {
      dateInput.showPicker();
      // A date picker is shown.
    } catch (error) {
      // Use external library when this fails.
    }
  });
</script>
```

A browser picker can also be prepopulated with items from `<datalist>` or "autocomplete".

See https://developer.chrome.com/blog/show-picker/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker

Answer (score 6):

You don't.

You can't tell (/force) the phone to show the date-picker without a user touching a `date` input.

Which is a good thing, because (at least on iOS) the native datepicker hides the normal browser controls at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Doesn't get me what I want, but it gives me the answer.  I guess, back to a custom built datepicker :(

Comment: This answer is wrong in 2023, at least on Firefox and Chrome for Android, `showPicker()` lets you programmatically show the input picker. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/show-picker/

Answer (score 3):

You can,

but it requires any input from the user e.g. touch/click event. From there you can use either `yourdateinput.click()` or `yourdateinput.focus()`. The first one is for android, the last one works on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for this answer