# How to know when a InputElement system picker has been closed without change

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var input  = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "datetime-local";

input.onchange =
function()
{ 
 console.log("date set");
} 

input.showPicker();
```

The code above will show a Date/Time picker.
Upon selecting a date, the onchange even is fired, as expected.

However, if the user simply clicks outside the picker, to cancel,
what event - if any - gets fired?

onblur doesn't seem to work.

So far the only very ugly solution I could find,
is to create a full window, top-layer invisible div,
and capture the "exit click" through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers were right that the picker could not be shown unless a user action triggered it: I was testing from the console only, and from the console apparently this constraint doesn't apply.

The element also needs to be appended to the DOM.

focus(), however, will not work if the element has any of these characteristics:

- display:none
- visibility:hidden
- zIndex less than 0

Finally I had to resort to setting the input's height and width to 0,
but also opacity to 0, because a few pixels would still show.

https://www.number137.com/lab/picker/

```
<html>
    <body style = "display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center">
        <div id = "picker" style = "cursor:hand">Pick</div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>

document.getElementById("picker").onclick =
function()
{
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.type             = "datetime-local";
 input.style.position   = "absolute";
 input.style.zIndex     = - 10;
 input.style.width      = "0px";
 input.style.height     = "0px";
 input.style.opacity    = 0;
 
 document.body.appendChild(input);

 input.onchange = 
 function(event)
 {
  console.log(input.value);
 } 

 input.onblur = 
 function(event)
 {
  console.log("nothing");
 }
 
 input.showPicker(); 
 input.focus();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `onblur` listener, and immediately after you call `showPicker`, set it to be focused as well, so that the blur triggers (which is why it doesn't work now, because there was no focus event, when picker gets shown programmatically).

(Note: to trigger native datepicker programmatically, it requires  [a user action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997045/how-to-programmatically-invoke-the-native-datepicker-on-a-mobile-device))

Try this:

```js
var input  = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "datetime-local";

document.querySelector('#test').append(input);

input.onchange =
function()
{ 
 console.log("date set");
} 

input.onblur =
function()
{ 
 console.log("closed onblur");
} 

input.showPicker();

input.focus();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Also, I can show the picker programmatically without a user action, and it doesn't need to be appended to the dom.

The problem you might be encountering is that a picker can't be shown programmatically from a cross-origin iframe or a non-secure context.

Comment: I appended it only for showcase, the key is to add `onblur` and call `focus()`. Can you include a reproducible example how exactly you're using it

Comment: you should get an error when calling it directly, but calling it from somewhere else on some user action, and then calling `.focus()` should have `onblur` triggering, as well as opening it manually, so you should include more information/code